# HC-05 BT Doesnt need vcc for power

Tags: bluetooth, troubleshooting

I'm hooking up and old  HC-05 BT module and it powers even if vcc is disconnected, (if TX is high and is key is high), is it likely i fried something and it's broken?

Comment: The related question shows why this happens. If you keep it up, you may burn out a chip but if you connect Vcc and it works, you're probably ok.

Comment: The ESD diodes to Vdd are only rated for 5mA

Answer (score 1):

There are diodes used for electro static discharge protection that will route power to the VCC rails when a pin is at a higher voltage than VCC. You should not rely on this. Connect VCC properly.